# hide HTML elements after logging in

Tags: php, html

I try to login with one PHP file, without any HTML files. So when I'm successfully logged in I want to hide the HTML post button and the textboxes.

Here's my code..:

```
 <?php 

    $showHTML = true;

    if ($showHTML) { ?>

    <h1> Bitte einloggen! </h1>
    <form action="test2.php" method="POST">
    <input name="user" type="test"><br>
    <input name="pass" type="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value"Login">
    </form>

    <?php 

    }

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

        if ( $_POST['user'] == "test" && $_POST['pass'] == "a123" ) {
            echo "user = test";
            $showHTML = false;
         }
     }
```

Of course that doesn't hide the HTML code again, because its already executed I think.

Is there any way to hide the HTML output again?

Comment: you can use `javascript/jquery` for this......

Comment: You *can* use JavaScript for this, it would be a more complicated and less reliable approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course that doens´t hide the HTMLCode again, because its already executed I think.

Correct

> Is there any way to hide the HTML output again?

Move the test so it appears *before* the HTML you (don't) want to output.

Answer (score 0):

Short: put the HTML under the PHP.

Long: Use a decent login system. Use sessions.

Comment: Thaaank you.. Of course you're right. That does work. I only need it for myself, so I won't use sessions for it :) Thank you all for the awnsers

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a server side variable to control the already rendered html content.

```
<?php 
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if ( $_POST['user'] == "test" && $_POST['pass'] == "a123" ) {
        echo "user = test";
　　} 
} else { ?>

<h1> Bitte einloggen! </h1>
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">
<input name="user" type="test"><br>
<input name="pass" type="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value"Login">
</form>

<?php } ?>
```